# Typing things Backwards

Tags: vb.net

My teacher has asked us to take a sentence that we input and make the console write it backwards. I understand that step is probably the best way to do it, but I am confused when it comes to the other parts.
I also believe that I'll need to use an array.

```
For i = 8 To 1 Step -1

    Console.WriteLine(myarray(i - 1))

Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

This is the code I am going to try and base the program on. Any tips?

Comment: The Homework tag is deprecated.

Comment: ... and here's the link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is already an implicit `Char()`.

```
Dim sentence = "Hello World"
For i = sentence.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Console.Write(sentence(i))
Next
```

or, if you can use LINQ

```
Dim backwards = sentence.Reverse()
Dim bwSentence = New String(backwards.ToArray())
```

Comment: To be pedantic, your second example has nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: It's sitting in the `System.Linq` namespace and is implemented using deferred execution.

Comment: Point taken, but it is just an extension method that just happens to exist in that namespace.  It could have been defined anywhere.  Is deferred execution one of the features of LINQ?  Isn't LINQ the particular keywords in the language (From, Select, Where, etc) that the compiler translates into the appropriate extension methods?

Comment: `Enumerable.Select`, `Enumerable.Where`, `Enumerable.GroupBy` etc. are also only extension methods in `Enumerable` class.  LINQ is a query language and `Enumerable.Reverse` is a query because it's not executed immediately. I could take the last two chars by `backwards.Take(2)` and would only enumerate two chars.

Comment: I understand, and don't disagree but my point is that it's the query language that is the "Language Itegrated" part of LINQ.  The extension methods exists apart from any language.  Isn't Take method is implemented using an iterator (yield return)?  Except for being an extension method, that could be implemented in .Net 2.0 couldn't it?  What makes it's execution deferred?  Do you have any links that explain this further?

Comment: What it makes it deferred is the `yield`, but even if it exists since .Net 2, it is a core feature of LINQ. The query syntax is just another (less powerful) way to express Linq queries than the method syntax. A Linq query always consists  of three steps. The DataSource, the query and the execution. So `Dim sentence = "Hello World"` is the DataSource(an `IEnumerable<Char>`,  a query variable initialized with a query expression). `Dim backwards = sentence.Reverse()` is the definition of the query. `Dim bwSentence = New String(backwards.ToArray())` is the execution (actually `ToArray())`.